# how to use if condition in cursor at time of declaration in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have query like below

```
Declare Cur_1 cursor for 

        if @EmployeeId <> is not null
            begin
                select EmployeeID from tbl_Employee where EEmployeeStatus='Active' and EmployeeID = @EmployeeId
            end
        else
            begin
                select EmployeeID from tbl_Employee where EEmployeeStatus='Active'
            end

Open Cur_1

    Fetch next from Cur_1 into @EmpId   
    While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    Begin

    end
Close Cur_1
deallocate Cur_1
```

but it's not working. it's show me syntax error.

it's show syntax error in if condition..

please help me.......

Comment: `if @EmployeeId is not null`, there is no need for <>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if @Feild is not null
      begin
            Declare your_Cursor_Name cursor for     
                    select Feild1 from Your_table where 1=1
        end
    else
        begin
            Declare your_Cursor_Name cursor for     
                    select Feild1 from Your_table where 1=1
         end

    Open your_Cursor_Name 

        Fetch next from your_Cursor_Name into @xyz
        While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        Begin
             `enter code here
        end
Close your_Cursor_Name
```

Comment: maybe you need to eplain a little about your answer code

Comment: Sure ..next time am care about this...Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The Corrrect syntax must be: `if @EmployeeId is not null`

there is no need for <> before is not null since `is` is the operator here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the if construction inside the cursor, instead have two possible declarations :

```
   if @EmployeeId is not null
      begin
            Declare Cur_1 cursor for     
                    select EmployeeID from tbl_Employee where EEmployeeStatus='Active' and EmployeeID = @EmployeeId
        end
    else
        begin
            Declare Cur_1 cursor for     
                    select EmployeeID from tbl_Employee where EEmployeeStatus='Active'
         end

    Open Cur_1

        Fetch next from Cur_1 into @EmpId   
        While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        Begin

        end
    Close Cur_1
    deallocate Cur_1
```